# Explicit type conversion (functional notation) with simple-type-specifier

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer

Porting some code I have discovered that line

```
unsigned char uc = unsigned char(c);
```

is accepted by MSVC but rejected by GCC. Is this syntax correct?
Standard says that

> A simple-type-specifier (7.1.7.2) ... followed by a parenthesized
>   optional expressionlist or by a braced-init-list (the initializer)
>   constructs a value of the specified type given the initializer

Does it mean that MS is right? Is `unsigned char` a 'simple-type-specifier'?

Comment: What is the (variable?) `c`?

Comment: What error does GCC produce? I think GCC is correct as `char(c)` is a type-cpecifier, but how to treat `unsegned` then? If they wanted to cast `c`, they could've written `(unsigned char)(c)` instead.

Comment: @dfri it is a `char` variable

Comment: @ForceBru expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'

Comment: Looks like a MSVC extension. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) a simple type specifier is either `char` or `unsgined` (int being deduced here). The rule list doesn't describe a way in which `unsigned char` can be treated as one. However you can `typedef` it, and *that* will be considered a simple type specifier.

Comment: @StoryTeller Good call.  Maybe MSVS uses table 9 instead of paragraph 1 in [\[dcl.type.simple\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple)

Comment: @NathanOliver, must be it! But the difference between the table and the paragraph is mildly annoying... Especially given the table's description.

Comment: @StoryTeller It had me scratching my head.  It is a *little* ambiguous.

Comment: @NathanOliver No it's not ambiguous, standard stated that table 9 is a summary of the valid **combinations** of simple-type-specifiers. "Table [tab:simple.type.specifiers] summarizes the valid combinations of simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify."

Comment: @songyuanyao Aha!  I did not read paragraph 2.  Just reading the title of the table though *Table 9 — simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify* is what made it ambiguous to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes the title is ambiguous indeed. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[GCC](http://rextester.com/FIZK9146) and [CLANG](http://rextester.com/DRLIG49758) are correct, the code is not valid.

[Simple type specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#1) is single-word type name:

> The simple type specifiers are
>
> ```
> simple-type-specifier:
>     nested-name-specifieropt type-name
>     nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id
>     nested-name-specifieropt template-name
>     char
>     char16_t
>     char32_t
>     wchar_t
>     bool
>     short
>     int
>     long
>     signed
>     unsigned
>     float
>     double
>     void
>     auto
>     decltype-specifier
>
> type-name:
>     class-name
>     enum-name
>     typedef-name
>     simple-template-id
>
> decltype-specifier:
>   decltype ( expression )
>   decltype ( auto )
> ```

`unsigned char` is not a simple-type-specifier, it's a **combination** of simple-type-specifiers, as shown in [Table 9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#tab:simple.type.specifiers) from standard.

> Table [tab:simple.type.specifiers] summarizes the valid combinations of simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify.
>
> Table 9 — simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify
>
> ```
> Specifier(s)  Type
> ...
> unsigned char     “unsigned char” 
> ...
> ```

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)'s an explanation from cppreference.com:

> 2) The functional cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (in other words, a single-word type name: `unsigned int(expression)` or `int*(expression)` are not valid), followed by a single expression in parentheses.

Answer (score -2):

or you can use:

```
unsigned char uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c);
```